# determinant of $4\times 4$ matrix by elimination

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to find the determinant of this $4\times 4$ matrix.

I got the wrong answer but I can't find the mistake

The answer is supposed to be $-44$ but I got $-176$

the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 &  3&  -3\\
    -3 & 3 & -1  & 2\\
     1 & 0 &  2 & -1\\
     1 & 0  & 2  & 3
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
[the problem and the way I solved it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCG8b.jpg)

thank you!!

Comment: Please show your work so we can help you spot where you made your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your equations, instead of pictures.

Comment: In the third matrix, how did you get Row 3 to be 0,2,7,-5

Comment: When you reduced the line, if you multiply a line by a constant, it multiply the determinant also. When you did $2R_3-R_1$ and $2R_2-3R_1$, it multiplied the determinant by a factor $2$, each time. Then $\det A=-(-2\cdot2\cdot(-11)\cdot4)/(2\cdot2)=-44$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

You have multiplied two fold by $2$ the columns so the determinant is multiplied by $4$.